# Adding file names from list to dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I previously used the script below to find all csv files in a folder and append them to a dataframe. Now I want to append specified files to a new dataframe.

```
#define path for all CSV files
path = r'C:filepath'
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

li = []

#removes rows with missing data and appends file to data frame
for csv in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df.loc[(df['A'].notna()) & (df['B'].notna()) & (df['C'].notna())]
    li.append(df)
```

what I would like to do is add something like:

```
file_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

To add only the files in the file list to the df.

Comment: `for csv in ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']:`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a list, you can loop through the items in the list and perform your desired action:

```
file_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
for csv in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df.loc[(df['A'].notna()) & (df['B'].notna()) & (df['C'].notna())]
    li.append(df)
```

Comment: I need a path specified as above, since they are not located in the same directory.

Comment: @geostats21 - what do you mean as above?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, thanks largely in part to gtomer.

```
for file in file_list:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path + file + '.csv', index_col=None, header=0)
        df = df.loc[(df['A'].notna()) & (df['B'].notna()) & (df['C'].notna())]
        li.append(df)
    except:
        print(file)
```